# Add lines to file according to a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file where every first line starts with `---` and next line starts with `Red`, So i'm looking to place some content like `Red Hat Release not determined` if there is not a line which stars with `Red` after the `---` line.

#### Below is my text file:

```
--- dpc2079.gpon.com ---
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo)
--- dpc2078.gpon.com ---
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo)
--- dpc2084.gpon.com ---
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo)
--- dpc2086.gpon.com ---
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo)
--- dpc2085.gpon.com ---
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo)
--- dpc2083.gpon.com ---
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo)
--- dpc2095.gpon.com ---
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo)
--- dpc2094.gpon.com ---
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo)
--- inv0313.gpon.com ---
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.10 (Santiago)
--- inv0270.gpon.com ---
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.11 (Tikanga)
--- inv0328.gpon.com ---
--- inv0535.gpon.com ---
--- dpc2081.gpon.com ---
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo)
```

#### Expected:

```
--- dpc2079.gpon.com ---
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo)
--- dpc2078.gpon.com ---
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo)
--- dpc2084.gpon.com ---
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo)
--- dpc2086.gpon.com ---
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo)
--- dpc2085.gpon.com ---
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo)
--- dpc2083.gpon.com ---
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo)
--- dpc2095.gpon.com ---
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo)
--- dpc2094.gpon.com ---
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo)
--- inv0313.gpon.com ---
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.10 (Santiago)
--- inv0270.gpon.com ---
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.11 (Tikanga)
--- inv0328.gpon.com ---
Red Hat Release not determined   <--
--- inv0535.gpon.com ---
Red Hat Release not determined    <--
--- dpc2081.gpon.com ---
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo)
```

#### My trial:

I am just learning hence not able to get how to do the above, any hint or solution will be very much appreciated.

```
>>> with open("test_release") as f:
...   for line in f:
...     line = line
...     if line.startswith('---'):
...       print(line)
...
--- dpc2079.gpon.com ---

--- dpc2078.gpon.com ---
```

Comment: @PranavHosangadi, thnx for being candid, my apologies i could not make it more clear as i am just an enthusiast who doesn't belong to computer or python background but sensed some deep interest in it while working on some of my project as being Micro-biological Re-searcher. thank you.. I'll better prepare my-self then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of suggestions:

- You should work with 2 files (at least during development), otherwise you might loose the original
- The part `line = line` does nothing meaningful
- You need to manage expectations: Once a '--- ...'-line was processed you need to memorise that the next one should be a 'Red ...'-line

Here's a proposal with a lot of comments:

```
file_in = 'test_release'
file_out = file_in + '_modified'
with open(file_in, 'r') as f_in, open(file_out, 'w') as f_out:

    # Initialize expectation flag: starting with False assumes that input file
    # always starts with a '--- ...'-line
    expect_red_line = False
    for line in f_in:
        # Strip whitespace at start and end (just to make sure) and add a
        # newline at the end
        line = line.strip() + '\n'
        # Check if a line starting with 'Red ...' is expected
        if expect_red_line:
            # Adjust expectation for next line
            expect_red_line = False
            # If expectation isn't met ...
            if not line.startswith('Red '):
                #  ... use the filler ...
                line = 'Red Hat Release not determined\n' + line
                # ... and make sure that the expectation is on for the next
                # line
                expect_red_line = True
            # Write the line(s) in output file
            f_out.write(line)
        # No line starting with 'Red ...' expected
        else:
            # Write the line in output file
            f_out.write(line)
            # Adjust expectation for next line
            expect_red_line = True
```

Be aware: I do not know how your input file could look like. If there's potential for deviation from what you have shown above then the code probably needs to be adjusted accordingly.

**EDIT**: This didn't catch missing last lines. To make sure they are also addressed add this snippet at the end:

```
    # Just in case the last line is also missing
    if expect_red_line:
        f_out.write('Red Hat Release not determined')
```

Comment: Timus, it works perfectly except if the last line where `Red` is missing also.

Comment: You are right, I didn't think of this case. The devil is always in the details :) I did add a catch line at the end that should fix it (hopefully).